# No adapter attached; skipping layout inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm having this annoying issue, even tho my previous apps didn't experience such bug,

I have the `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView`, and the params are set correctly. Looking at the code, i have the `setAdapter` method after the `setLayoutManager`

As you can see in the code, I'm adding an empty `ArrayList`, and setting the `LayoutManager` first, after that i have `setNestedScrollingEnabled` to `false`, finally I'm setting the `Adapter`.

In the XML, I have it as `wrap_content`.

Still, i'm experiencing this error, and my app just FC afterwards.

Code:

```
if(mRecyclerView == null)
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_section_home_recyclerview);

    mGiftsItemsList = new ArrayList<>();

    LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mLinearLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new AdapterFragmentSectionHome(getActivity(),mGiftsItemsList);
    mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);


    setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ListenerInterfaceHomeClick() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
            if(mGiftsItemsList.get(position).isGiveaway_has_finished()){

            } else {
                if(getActivity() != null){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ActivityGy.class);

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.GIVEAWAY_IS_ANIMATED,true);
                        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),Pair.create(v, "cardview") );
                        try{
                            startActivity(intent,options.toBundle());
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else 
                    {
                        try{
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator();
    if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) { ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false); }
```

Layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_section_home_nestedscrollview"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_section_home_nestedscrollview_layout">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_section_home_recyclerview"
            android:scrollbars="none"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: can you please post what error your getting ?

Comment: if(mRecyclerView == null) why are you creating if here ? No adapter attached; skipping layout inside NestedScrollView means that your recyclerview has no adapter attached to it. You must set an adapter to it then when the data comes you just call the .notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Try it without the NestedScrollView. I had a same problem yesterday.

Comment: * I can't use it without ScrollView, as i have more than a RecyclerView in the Layout.

Comment: Checking if null, as i have faced a way where the RecyclerView in the Fragment doesn't get called and assigned (value from Fragment's onView), therefore just wanted to check if it's null or not.

Comment: The error is the same as the one in the title, only this, along with a "buffer reading error" with a red color.

Answer (score 0):

In a project of mine, I also encounter this but no crash.

> RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Here is how I defined my elements (focused on the recycler, that is displaying a grid):

**layout.xml**:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- stuff here -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/myRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**Activity.java**:

```
@VisibleForTesting
RecyclerView myRecycler;
private MyAdapter myRecyclerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setLayout();
}

private void setLayout() {
    myRecycler = findViewById(R.id.myRecycler);
    ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(myRecycler, false);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setLayoutValues();
}

private void setLayoutValues() {
    myRecyclerAdapter = new MyAdapter();
    int nbCols = 2;
    GridLayoutManager layout = new GridLayoutManager(this, nbCols);
    myRecycler.setLayoutManager(layout);
    myRecycler.setAdapter(myRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

I hope you could inspire from it and solve your issue :)

Comment: The solution didn't work.I have a list view, and this listview opens an activity which has a RecyclerView inside it. When i double click on it, it crashes with the *No adapter* message. The issue is that the Adapter is not yet set when i'm clicking? i really don't understand the issue as i'm setting it correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by when I double click on it? Why double click? What is  "it" there, the listview item, the recyclerview item?
Could you post also the code of the listview, so we could see how you navigate to this one?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
You have to add Layout Manager to your RecyclerView From xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" >
```

and
from code after recycler view initialization

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything, adding manager from XML is equivalent of adding it in code in terms of functionality

Comment: @Tuby you should atleast try this as this worked for me when I was facing the same issue.